# Get all links in a web page with xpath condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xpath

For a give web page, I am able to extract all links in it by using `document.links`. However, I want to exclude the links which contains `href="javascript:void(0)"`

I am trying to exclude such links using xpath like this `document.links.evaluate("//a[not(@href='javascript:void(0)')]", document)` but unable to filter it out.

Please suggest a workaround

[image]

Comment: Why not come into the 21st century and use `document.querySelectorAll("a[href!='javascript:void(0)']")`? `document.links` is an ancient API and XPath is not necessary on an HTML DOM Document.

Comment: @ScottMarcus when i did that I am getting error as `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'a[href!='javascript:void(0)']' is not a valid selector.
`

Comment: @ScottMarcus `!=` is not a valid attribute selector operator. But there is `a:not([href="javascript:void(0)"])`

Comment: thanks a lot... it worked now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CSS directly

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href="javascript:void(0)"])');

console.log(links.length)
```

```html
<a href="something">something</a>
<a href="http://some.where">some.where</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">void</a>
<a href="https://somewhere.else">somewhere.else</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure to test whatever is in the link, you can filter first

```js
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")]
  .filter(lnk => !lnk.href.includes("javascript:"))
  .map(lnk => lnk.href)

console.log(links)
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link1</a>
<a href="https://google.com">Link2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link3</a>
<a href="https://mdn.com">Link4</a>
```